# CMultiFileUpload does not show selected files

Tags: php, yii, cmultifileupload

I am using `CMultiFileUpload` to upload multiple files. Using `htmlOptions` I can get `multiple=>multiple` to work, and multiple files gets stored in the database. However, after every selection from the `input` dialog box, there should be the name of the file, along with a remove button right beside it, [like the user here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21538453/yii-cmultifileupload-stop-default-behavior) has. In my case, this didn't show up. `'accept'`, `'duplicate'`,`'remove'` and `'denied'` also do not work.

Here is my view:

```
<?php
    $this->widget('CMultiFileUpload', array(
        'name'=>'files',
        'accept'=>'pdf',
        'duplicate'=>'File already selected!',
        'remove'=>'[x]',
        'htmlOptions' => array('multiple'=>'multiple'),
        'denied'=>'File is not allowed',
        'max'=>10
    ));
?>
```

These are the results: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M95dr.png) and [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwZcZ.png)

Can anyone please point out where I went wrong?

Comment: Remove 'htmlOptions' and post browser console screen please, is there some errors?